# Attach and retrive multiple pdf files to post or page

Tags: php, posts, attachments, pdf

I need to create two sections that will respectively contains only some pdf to downloads. I've never used pdf inside a wordpress websites, my question is how I can display them or in any case had a list of them? I was thinking about attaching the files to the relative post/page, this to avoid confusion between the different files that I will display on the two different sections. Can anyone suggest me a smart and fast way to achieve this (files attaching)?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin. Go for the PRO version, since you might need it's functionality (it costs less than 20 USD) and will be one of the best WordPress related investments.

You should look at the [Repeater](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/) field (two of them, one for each section) and put a [File](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/file/) field as repeater's row. They you need to display these fields on the front-end.

The documentation is amazing and easy to understand even for a complete beginner.

Comment: Ok,I know about that plugin, but unfotunately my client will not pay for an extra plugin to have this possibility so I was looking for a reference or a code snippet that will let me achieve this with php and wp core functions

Comment: @sialfa You can definitely code everything that ACF offers on your own. Make some custom meta fields, code the upload forms in the back end and and attempt to display it on the front end, but it will take you much, much more time and effort. There is no point in reinventing the wheel. 20 bucks is really nothing. But if you somehow can't afford it, there are still ways to get the Pro version free, right? But we do not support that over here.

Comment: It's not a question of the needed time, the point is that if a client have a budget, it's supposed that the developer respect it. Moreover a professional developer needs to know how to create custom components and not use a plugin of a third party to do something in wordpress. Plugins are helpful but sometimes they are created from developers for user with no programming skills in general. This is why I don't like to work with wordpress. Too many developers are using plugins but don't know how to make the things on their own.

Comment: @sialfa Are you not charging your client? Are you working for free? If you charge 10 cents an hour it is reasonable to code it yourself. If not, ACF is 100 times cheaper. So yes - if you want to respect client's budget, buy ACF for 20 bucks. Also, I am a web developer, I work with wordpress 8 hours a day, and again - there is absolutely no point in reinventing the wheel. I like to use my own code instead of bloated plugins, but it is not the case of ACF.